# How do I create an executable JAR file from my intellij project?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, executable-jar

I've been having a hell of a time figuring out why jar says it cannot find the main class

Project:
4 class files
properties file
2 libraries (from Maven)

Manifest file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: all.GuiApp
```

All classes are in the same package "all"

I added the artifact in intellij artifacts - and specified the main class. Tried both options there for 'extract to JAR' and 'copy to output and link'

When I double click it, it does nothing.
When I execute it from command line it gives me a message that it cannot find the main class. I am not sure what else I can try to make it work.

Edit:
Running the following command actually got me 1 step closer, Does it somehow not see the manifest file? How do I make sure it is looking in the right place?

```
java -classpath jarName.jar all.GuiApp
```

After this step it is telling me it cannot find my properties file. I even replicated src/main/resources folder structure and added the file there (as well as in the root jar archive, but it still cannot load it.

POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>updateTimes</groupId>
    <artifactId>update_ms</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.53</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

main declaration in GuiApp:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
```

Comment: Can you provide your maven pom file?  Also, does your GuiApp have a public static void main(String[] args) method?

Comment: @java1337 added pom file, and yup, main declaration is as you stated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the issue is that my manifest file that I can see is correct in intellij, is getting overwritten by maven libraries. From what I see I need to create one jar for just the external libraries, and compile my code separately.

I corrected the issue (with help of coworker) by just using external jar files of jch and mongo. Which I then referenced in the class path. Since I didn't have the external libraries anymore, my manifest file did not get overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `mvn package`. Based on the [maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/usage.html) you should be able to get the jar after running this command.

Comment: Tried to do it with mvn and it is giving me an error
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read art
ifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-resources-plugin:pom:2.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path
 building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested targ
et

Comment: also although for now I am looking for any way to make it work, I want to find out why it does not work with intellij